# ggplot manual label with characters as icons

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a multilayered plot that includes individual points (solid dots), means per class (bordered dot) and "***" indicating p.values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#layer1
layer1<- data.frame("class1"= sample(c("tall", "medium", "short"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                    "class2"= sample(c("red", "blue"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                    "value"= runif(100))
layer1<- melt(layer1)

#layer2
layer2<- data.frame("class1"= rep(c("tall", "medium", "short"), each=2),
                    "class2"= rep(c("red", "blue"), 3),
                    "value"= runif(6))

#layer3
layer3<- data.frame("class1"= c("tall", "medium", "short"),
                    "tag"= c("***", "**", "*"))

#el plot
plot<- ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=class1, y=value, col=class2), data=layer1, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=class1, y=value, fill=class2), data=layer2, shape=21, size=2, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=class1, y=1), data=layer3, label=layer3$tag)
```

I want to build a legend similar to this
[image: desired legend]
but I am having troubles getting it done. 
Is there some kind of manual legend function that I can add as part of the ggplot, like 
magic_legend(title= legend title, icons=c(1, 1, 21, ***, **, *), fills=c(red, blue), labels = c(name1, name2, mean, p<0.001, p<0.01, p<0.05)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it took some puzzling but this is about as good as I can do. You would have to set the scale for each aesthetic of interest and cheat a little bit by overriding the colour scale keys.

```
plot<- ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=class1, y=value, colour=class2), 
             data=layer1, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=class1, y=value, shape="Mean", fill = class2), 
             data=layer2, size=2, colour = "black",
             position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=class1, y=1, label = tag), 
            data=layer3) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, colour = NA))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 21) +
  scale_discrete_manual("label", 
                        values = c("*", "**", "***"),
                        labels = c("p<0.05", "p<0.01", "p<0.001"))

plot
```

[image]

Comment: Great work, you may want to add a little `labs(shape='',label='',color='',fill='')` line at the end and legend titles will be hidden :)

Comment: This was a lot less cumbersome than I had expected, although I still have a hard time understanding the logic behind. Removing label titles as suggested by @Lokinou and then adding a + theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.2, "cm") to remove the excessive spacing between legens ended up in a very good final result.

Comment: Well, ggplot2 has mysteries, but one important one to unveil is the aes() asesthetics. Whatever is inside is parsed along the data provided especially colors, shapes and so on. Whatever is outside aes is applies only once and does not show up in legend. What @teunbrand did was redefining scales, and on one case just overriding the associated legend. He redefined fill, color, shape and labels scales in either a discrete or manual manner. My addition was only to remove the titles. It gets easier with practice ;)